# Prevent R `plotly` plot axes from being resized after hiding a group of points

Tags: r, r-plotly

I use **R** package **plotly** to create a 3D scatterplot. I want to compare how the plot looks when one or several groups are hidden. How can I prevent axes from being resided when I "turn off" (hide) one of the groups by clicking on the legend?

```r
library(plotly)

# Data
set.seed(20180727)
my_data <- 
    data.frame(x = c(rnorm(20, mean = 0), rnorm(20, mean = 0),  rnorm(20, mean = 2)),
               y = c(rnorm(20, mean = 0), rnorm(20, mean = -5), rnorm(20, mean = 8)),
               z = c(rnorm(20, mean = 0), rnorm(20, mean = 8),  rnorm(20, mean = 4)),
               group = gl(3, 20, labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
    )


# Plotly settings
scene0 <- list(xaxis = list(range = range(my_data$x), autorange = FALSE),
               yaxis = list(range = range(my_data$y), autorange = FALSE),
               zaxis = list(range = range(my_data$z), autorange = FALSE))

# Plot
plot_ly(my_data,
        x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
        color     = ~group,
        type      = "scatter3d",
        mode      = "markers",
        marker    = list(opacity = 0.6, size = 4)
) %>%
    plotly::layout(scene = scene0)
```

All groups:

[image]

One group is hidden and, unfortunately, axes got resized:

[image]

Comment: can you instead change their color to "transparent" or opacity to zero?

Answer (score 2):

Dirty trick

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
# Data
set.seed(20180727)
my_data <- 
  data.frame(x = c(rnorm(20, mean = 0), rnorm(20, mean = 0),  rnorm(20, mean = 2)),
         y = c(rnorm(20, mean = 0), rnorm(20, mean = -5), rnorm(20, mean = 8)),
         z = c(rnorm(20, mean = 0), rnorm(20, mean = 8),  rnorm(20, mean = 4)),
         group = gl(3, 20, labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
  )

rangex = range(my_data$x)
rangey = range(my_data$y)
rangez = range(my_data$z)

# Plot
plot_ly(my_data,
        x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
        color     = ~group,
        type      = "scatter3d",
        mode      = "markers",
        marker    = list(opacity = 0.6, size = 4)
) %>%
  add_trace(y = rangey[2],x=rangex[2],z=rangez[2],type      = "scatter3d",showlegend = FALSE,opacity=0) %>%
  add_trace(y = rangey[1],x=rangex[1],z=rangez[1],type      = "scatter3d",showlegend = FALSE,opacity=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well and the problem is solved by manually specifying 'aspectratio' within the 'scene' parameter of layout. Set whatever ratio you want, here 1:1:1.2. You can append this onto your current scene parameters.

Try:

```
noresize_scene = list(aspectmode='manual',
  aspectratio = list(x=1, y=1, z=1.2))

plot_ly(my_data,
        x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
        color     = ~group,
        type      = "scatter3d",
        mode      = "markers",
        marker    = list(opacity = 0.6, size = 4)
) %>%
    plotly::layout(scene = noresize_scene)
```